# Missing numbers inside square

Tags: mathematics, visual, calculation-puzzle

Below puzzle have some missing number .Can you find them ?  .

[image]

Hint #1

> Start solving from ↑(Top)

Hint #2

> Look closely there is some pattern inside ever rectangle which lead you to next answer

Hint #3

> Divide then add or subtract .Start from upper rectangle and look for the pattern.

Comment: Is it intentional that the 90 and 70 in the middle right rectangle are not aligned?

Comment: I didn't observed that :P nothing intentional its my drawing mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image: numbSQ]
In the first column all numbers are multiples of 5. In the last column all numbers are multiples of 7. By addition and subtraction we obtain (63 + 70 + 56) - (60 + 55 + 65) = 3^2. In the second column and the fifth column, all numbers are multiples of 10 plus one prime. By addition and subtraction we obtain (800 + 80 + 200 + 40 +3) - (160 + 13 + 400 + 20 + 430) = 10^2. In the third column and the fourth column all numbers are multiples of 5. By addition and subtraction we obtain (55 + 90 + 985) - (1065 + 30 + 10) = 5^2. So the missing numbers are 55, 1065, 13, 56 (shown outside the square).

Comment: Good try ,but none of your answer are correct .Hint ( look closely in each rectangle there is some pattern )  .

Answer (score 2):

May be answers are :

> 50,20,25,233.

Reason:

> Rectangle 1: 800/80=10 and 60-10=50 ,Rectangle 2: 63-55=8 and 160/8=20 ,Rectangle3: 200/40=5 and 30-5=25 similarly in Rectangle 4 : 400/20=20 and 90-20=70  ,Rectangle 5:10+3=13 and 13*5=65 ,Rectangle6: 985/5=197 and 430-197=233. This is because I observed that the rectangle in the same row have addition and subtraction  for example since second rectangle is 63 is greater than 55 we need to add 8 to 55 to get 63 so we have to subtract in the first rectangle i.e 60-10 =50. This same logic is followed in the next two rectangle in the next row so by that logic since we add 10 and 3 to ge 13 and multiply by 5 we need to subtract in the adjacent rectangle i.e 430-233=197 and 197*5 gives 985 so I reverse calculate using this logic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a great start to an answer but it would be even more helpful if you formatted in a more intuitive way. Either way, thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers could be

> **50, 20, 25, 7045**(the last one I'm unsure of, since there's only 3 areas instead of 4)

Explanation

> Rectangle1: 800/80=10. 60-10=**50**
>  || Rectangle2: 63-55=8. 160/8=**20**
>  || Rectangle3: 200/40=5. 30-5=**25**
>  || (Rectangle4): 400/20=20. 90-70=20
>  || (Rectangle5): 10+3=13. 13*5=65
>  || Rectangle6: 985+430=1415. 1415*5=**7075**

Comment: 3 are correct , only last one is wrong . hint rot13 (Qvivqr ovttre ahzore ol fbzrguvat naq gura fhogenpg vg ol bgure ahzore)